# Imagem ListView

Tags: asp.net, listview, imagem

Dificuldade:
Exibir uma imagem no item template do controle List View.
A propriedade datasource do controle é populada com uma coleção. Na coleção, a imagem retorna do SQlServer como um array de bytes.
Daí que preciso converte-lo em imagem no item template do controle.

```
         <ItemTemplate>
                <h2><%#Eval("titulo")%></h2>                                                                                                                      
                <p><h5><%#Eval("texto")%></h5></p>                                             
                <h6><%#Eval("data", "{0:d}")%></h6>   
                imagem convertida aqui
        </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: É ASP.NET? Ou qual linguagem?

Comment: sim, asp.net obrigado

Comment: Editei com uma tag nova para dar mais destaque a linguagem, assim um desenvolvedor que tenha o mesmo conhecimento em ASP.NET tem uma maior visibilidade sobre a pergunta. Aproveite e faça um tour sobre o Stackoverflow para aproveitar melhor os recursos oferecidos: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour. Seja bem-vindo.

Comment: sim tranquilo. obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Para obter como retorno um Image veja se o código abaixo te ajuda:

`public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
     Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
}`

Se preferir um BitmapImage:

`public BitmapImage ImageFromBuffer(Byte[] bytes)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
    image.BeginInit();
    image.StreamSource = stream;
    image.EndInit();
    return image;
}`

Comment: ok, obrigado. Gostaria de converter diretamente no controle.

Comment: Você pode fazer essa conversão no momento em que você estiver criando o seu objeto, então no atributo imagem dele você faz a conversão. Se eu entendi a sua questão rsrsrsr dê uma olhada nessa questão. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2629921/3737742

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse tuto: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/445876/Auto-bind-byte-to-asp-Image

Comment: o objeto é do tipo byte[]. Se eu converter não consigo adicionar na coleção. Por isso preciso converter no controle.

Comment: namespace ObjetoTransferencia
{
    public class BlogSite
    {

        public int textoID { get; set; }
        public string titulo { get; set; }        
        public string texto { get; set; }        
        public DateTime Data { get; set; }
        public byte[] imagem { get; set; }          
    } 
}

Comment: estudei muitos exemplos. Eu teria que mudar o projeto pra adequar. Busco a solução de conversão diretamente no controle.